# How to remove all whitespaces between tag-pairs inside <ul> element

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, html-lists, whitespace

I currently have the following content:

```
<section>
<hgroup>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Koptitel 1</h1>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Subtitel</h2>
</hgroup>
<ul class="sample1">
    <li class="sample2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum placerat, urna eget ultricies egestas, lectus mi tincidunt nulla, ut molestie odio lectus ut arcu.</li>
    <li class="sample2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum placerat, urna eget ultricies egestas, lectus mi tincidunt nulla, ut molestie odio lectus ut arcu."</li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Sandbox URL: http://regex101.com/r/zQ0lN5

I have the following code in PHP:

```
$new_content = preg_replace('/(?<=<ul class="sample1">|<\/li>)\s*?(?=<\/ul>|<li.*?>)/is', '', $content);
```

This works, the whitespaces between ul and li and between the li-items are removed so the expected output is.

```
<section>
<hgroup>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Koptitel 1</h1>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Subtitel</h2>
</hgroup>
<!-- SEE BELOW NO WHITE SPACES -->
<ul class="sample1"><li class="sample2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum placerat, urna eget ultricies egestas, lectus mi tincidunt nulla, ut molestie odio lectus ut arcu.</li><li class="sample2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum placerat, urna eget ultricies egestas, lectus mi tincidunt nulla, ut molestie odio lectus ut arcu."</li></ul>
</section>
```

I rather like to do the following:

```
//Ignore what's between < and > : <ul.*?>
$new_content = preg_replace('/(?<=<ul.*?>|<\/li>)\s*?(?=<\/ul>|<li.*?>)/is', '', $content);
```

So a coder can even add style or whatever in the ul tag and the code still won't break. However lookbehinds need to be zero-width, thus quantifiers are not allowed. So how do I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide example data and expected output?

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: PHP, I will rewrite the answer and question so it's more clear. Thanks in advance for the comments!

Comment: Sample data is provided here: http://regex101.com/r/zQ0lN5

Comment: if I got it right, you want to remove spaces between entire tags <ul>and <li> or between multiple <li> elements (like it stands in the title) and don't want to affect actual code?

Comment: Correct. It should remove all whitespace between <ul> and <li> and between </li> and <li> within a <ul></ul>. And it shouldn't matter what coders put in the UL or LI tag. so <ul style="blabla" class="blabla"> the whitespaces should still be removed.

Comment: PS. I updated the question, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: it isn't clear at all for me, please make it simple,`I have this` and `I want this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can do the trick? You **don't need** lookbehinds.

```
echo preg_replace("/[\s\n]*?(\<(\/ul>|li[\s>]))/i", "$1", $your_document);
```

Where `$your_document` is HTML code you want to deal with.

So, if this is your HTML:

```
<section>
<hgroup>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Koptitel 1</h1>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Subtitel</h2>
</hgroup>
<ul class="sample1">
    <li class="sample2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum placerat, urna eget ultricies egestas, lectus mi tincidunt nulla, ut molestie odio lectus ut arcu.</li>
    <li class="sample2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum placerat, urna eget ultricies egestas, lectus mi tincidunt nulla, ut molestie odio lectus ut arcu.</li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Output for that looks like:

```
<section>
<hgroup>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Koptitel 1</h1>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Subtitel</h2>
</hgroup>
<ul class="sample1"><li class="sample2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum placerat, urna eget ultricies egestas, lectus mi tincidunt nulla, ut molestie odio lectus ut arcu.</li><li class="sample2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum placerat, urna eget ultricies egestas, lectus mi tincidunt nulla, ut molestie odio lectus ut arcu.</li></ul>
</section>
```

This removes all whitespaces and new-line (`\n`) characters between `<ul> and <li>`, between `</li> and <li>`, and between `</li> and </ul>` tags making entire `<ul>` element written in one line with no spaces between `>` and `<` inside. This regular expression is not case-sensitive so it also looks for `<LI>` as well as `<li>`.

Comment: Thank you for your time, it works like a charm from what I can see it =) I will now dive into your regexp to see why haha.

Comment: simply, it captures all whitespaces and newlines before <li> and </ul> tags, together with these tags. then replaces entire match just with tag.. in short it replaces [spaces/newline][tag] with [tag]. that way it actually removes anything in front of that tag (in case it's sequence made of \s or \n chars).

Comment: `[\s>]` makes sure that it looks for `<li>` element, not `<list>` or anything else that starts with `<li`. It also works with `<li attrib="value">`.